# Join arrays with key and stay with value of second array

Tags: php

I have two arrays to join each other:

```
$array_1 = array(18 => 0
 , 19 => 0
 , 20 => 0
 , 21 => 0
 , 22 => 0
 , 23 => 0);

$array_2 = array(22 => 3
 , 23 => 4);

var_dump(array_merge($array_1, $array_2));
```

The result from this code:

```
array(8) { [0]=> int(0) 
 [1]=> int(0) 
 [2]=> int(0) 
 [3]=> int(0) 
 [4]=> int(0) 
 [5]=> int(0) 
 [6]=> int(3) 
 [7]=> int(4) }
```

The result I expect:

```
array(8) { [18] => int(0)
, [19] => int(0)
, [20] => int(0)
, [21] => int(0)
, [22] => int(3)
, [23] => int(4), }
```

How I can get expected results?

Comment: use array_replace instead of array_merge

Comment: Depending on desired end-results: `$a + $b`, `$b + $a`, or `array_replace($a, $b)` https://3v4l.org/0Z44r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use union of two arrays in good order :

```
$array_1 = array(18 => 0, 19 => 0, 20 => 0, 21 => 0, 22 => 0, 23 => 0);
$array_2 = array(22 => 3, 23 => 4);
var_dump($array_2 + $array_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

So simply convert the array keys to strings.